# AngularJs - my view gets reloaded when clicking any link on the index page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an AngularJs app with start up page as index.html and I am routing the user to projects page by default. The issue is whenever I click the dropdown-toggle link in my index.html page the projects partial view gets reloaded which shouldn't be. Please see the code below:

### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                            <i class="icon-tasks"></i>
                            <span class="badge badge-grey">4</span>
                        </a> 

<div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

### app.js

```
 $routeProvider
    .when('/projects',
    {
       controller: 'projectController',
       templateUrl: '/app/views/projects/projects.html'
    })       
    .when('/suppliers',
    {
       controller: 'supplierController',
       templateUrl: '/app/views/suppliers/suppliers.html'
    })       
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/projects' });
```

Also, I tried using $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); to remove the "#" from the URL and the reload got stopped but my url (`http://localhost/index.html#/projects`) becomes like this `http://localhost/projects` and I'll get a 404. Any idea how to solve the partial view reload issue?

Comment: Don't use anchor tag and use any span tag to achieve style but if you want anchor tag then use ng-click event and in controller try event.preventDefault()

Comment: Thanks for your response but as per @aduch answer ui.router worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to use `ui.router` to manage subviews, it seems to suit to your needs here.

[github here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

### [A good introduction to ui-router](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-introduction-ui-router)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never know about the ui.router plugin but after your guidance I used it and the page reload issue has gone away.